# Sharepoint broken. "Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401) "

Tags: restart

I am stabbing in the dark here trying to get a SharePoint 2010 server back up. Having just bounced IIS I am getting this when trying to open a SharePoint site:

> Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other
>   instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)

Problems started when the User Profile Service got messed up. It's been recreated but the "User Profile Synchronisation Service" is stuck "starting".

This is just a basic single server pilot system we're trying things out on. Any pointers to getting this back up would be greatly appreciated. Google isn't helping in this instance... ;)

I don't know where the problem is. All servies show "started" except the following:

> Claims to Windows Token Service
>   Document Conversions Launcher Service
>   Document Conversions Load Balancer Service 
>   Lotus Notes Connector
>   Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service

I don't know if any of them are relevant to this but am mentioning them just in case.

This site was working fine until the User Profile Service got messed up.

Thanks in advance to anyone able to help.

Comment: Still trying to get to bottom of this. I have the following in the logs: An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The HTTP service located at http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas is too busy. .

Comment: In case anyone stumbles on this, I have got my system up again. Something caused a number of application pools to have the wrong password. I re-entered the credentials on all such services and now my site is up again.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this on my dev server some time ago and what I did was add  to the web.config of the application. However, I would not advice you to go forward with this in production environment, but at least it will gauge you in the right direction towards troubleshooting the issue. Also please see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaskis/archive/2010/01/05/intermittently-getting-loading-this-assembly-would-produce-a-different-grant-set-from-other-instances-exception-from-hresult-0x80131401-after-net-3-5-sp-1.aspx

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: In our SharePoint 2013 environment after rebooting the farm consisting of 4 servers - on one of our WFE servers was throwing ---
EventID 8306 - Version 15 Level 2 Task 47 Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401) This error would also be clustered / combined with EventID 1325 1026 1000 We eventually came upon this post (after hours of trying to figure out root cause) While this was a shot in the dark and didn't make any sense why we'd need to re-enter passwords on the app pools; figured it wouldn't hurt. So that's what